# showModalBottomSheet dynamic height with ListView.builder not working

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, flutter-layout

I am trying to create **BottomSheet** based on content size but does not working. In Sheet i have used following widgets Container->Column->ListView Builder.

I tried following options but still not working as excepted.

```
isScrollControlled: true,
```

ListView Property :  `shrinkWrap: true,` and checked With **Wrap** widget also not working.

**Wrap** widget without **listview** is Working.

Please find the code :

```
class BottomStringlistController {
  var selectedValue = "";
  void showSheet(BuildContext context, List<String> values, String currentTitle, {required Function(String value) onCompletion}){
    var bottomSheet = showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      // isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return
          Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius:  BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15.0),
            ),
          ),
          child:
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child:
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child:  Expanded(
                child:  Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          currentTitle.toUpperCase(),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(14),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        IconButton(onPressed:(){
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.close,color: kPrimaryColor,),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Divider(color: kPrimaryColor,),
                    SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenWidth(15),),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: values.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            selectedValue = values[index];
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(values[index].toUpperCase(),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    color: Colors.black
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      onCompletion(selectedValue);
    });
  }
}
```

**SS Attached :**

[image: Output Image without isScrollControlled]

[image: Output Image with isScrollControlled]

I am learning flutter and noob at it.

My requirement like below:

Assume that i have less than 10 values **Sheet** has to adjust its size based on content. If more than 10, Sheet has to show **default size** with Scroll for remaining data... I hope u got my questions

Answer (score 1):

This example will help you to build showModalBottomSheet according to items size, Wrap with Listview.seprated

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );   } }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {   
 const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override   _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(); }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {   
List<String> l = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"];   
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
         showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                builder: (_, controller) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: controller,
                      itemCount: l.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(l[index]),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
        },
      ),
    );   } }
```

Comment: I have disabled it isScrollControlled: false, design going half of screen if values more but content not scrolling

Comment: @karthikeyan please check this one. I edited showModalBottomSheet

Comment: Why do we need DraggableScrollableSheet?

Comment: Assume that i have less than 10 values **Sheet** has to adjust its size based on content. If more than 10, Sheet has to show **default size** with Scroll for remaining data... I hope u got my questions

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: JustBanner())));
}

class JustBanner extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _JustBannerState();
  }
}

class _JustBannerState extends State<JustBanner> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body:
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            BottomStringlistController().showSheet(
                context,
                [
                  "test",
                  "test",
                  "test",
                  "test",
                  "test",
                  "test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
                  "test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
                  "test\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
                  "tes",
                  "tes",
                  "tes",
                  "tes",
                  "tes",
                  "tes",
                ],
                "Testtttt");
          },
          child: Text("Click"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomStringlistController {
  var selectedValue = "";

  void showSheet(BuildContext context, List<String> values, String currentTitle,
      {Function(String value) onCompletion}) {
     showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      currentTitle.toUpperCase(),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: values.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          selectedValue = values[index];
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              values[index].toUpperCase(),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      onCompletion(selectedValue);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it is working but if i add more values in list, the sheet taking default half screen and scrolling issue in bottom

Comment: use `SizeBox` instead of `const Spacer(),`

Comment: I changed to SizeBox still same issue can you suggest me with  demo code

Comment: you can try to wrap your column widget with the `Expanded` widget

Comment: Not working still same, Check my updated code.

Comment: updated my answer please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245442/discussion-between-jahidul-islam-and-karthikeyan).

Comment: I have disabled it isScrollControlled: false, design going half of screen if values more but content not scrolling

Comment: @karthikeyan check out the updated answer and you need to add `physics: ScrollPhysics(),` to list view

Comment: its completing disabling scroll, Consider what if i have more than 100 values...

Comment: Assume that i have less than 10 values **Sheet** has to adjust its size based on content. If more than 10, Sheet has to show **default size** with Scroll for remaining data... I hope u got my questions

Comment: got you and check my updated answer

Comment: Kindly check with array value of 5

Comment: it's working but what you get

Comment: Empty spaces at bottom, like first image in question

Comment: Any help would be appreciated?